# Cannot enable offline mode for ArcGIS Online web map in order to use in Esri Collector app

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-pro, web-mapping, arcgis-collector

I've been trying to enable offline mode in a WebMap in order to use one Collector. I reviewed the requirements [here](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector-classic/windows/create-maps/offline-map-prep.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_AB1D69C1F1B34FADBA997B918E97BE17) however I enabled sync and caching on my feature layer and map layer I believe. Here is the option in ArcServer Manager that shows it as enabled:

[image: Use tiles from cache]

[image: Feature Access]

[image: Sync]

What else can I check to ensure that I meet all the requirements in order to enable offline mode in WebMap? And how can I accomplish this. I see all the tutorials online refer to ArcMap, however, I use ArcGIS Pro and I'm having a hard time finding a tutorial that matches the products I'm using.

EDIT: I used the World Imagery Basemap for export from ArcGIS online from the tut included in the link above. This is th link to the basemap for Export: arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=226d23f076da478bba4589e7eae95952

Also I should mention that I want my data to upload to a geo-database when bringing in the data into the office for syncing.

Comment: "All editable feature layers in the map are either hosted feature layers or ArcGIS Server 10.4 or later feature services." https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/take-maps-offline.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_6CE94B6639C44D5AB860FD74256387CA the other option is to side-load the maps https://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector/ipad/help/offline-prep.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_20F822B9E7C54E4FAFF9B7032DE7471A

Comment: do the tile map services support export?

Comment: Well, @RussRoberts I used the World Imagery Basemap for export from ArcGIS online from the tut icluded in the link above. This is th link to the basemap: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=226d23f076da478bba4589e7eae95952

Comment: @Mapperz I guess I don't quite understand what it means to have a "hosted" feature layer. I published my feature layer from ArcGIS Pro and enabled Sync from there.

Comment: Hosted Feature Layers https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/hosted-web-layers.htm

Comment: Are you using this web map in ArcGIS Online or in Portal?

Comment: @RussRoberts in my locally hosted portal

Comment: @Mapperz It seems to me that a Hosted Feature Layer refences data that is copied and hosted from the Portal itself instead of the Data Source. I would like for my data to be uploaded into a referenced geo-database and not to be stored on the GIS Server. Would that be possible?

Comment: only zipped  (gdb.zip) > https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/supported-items.htm

Comment: Make sure that ALL of the feature services in the web map are hosted either in an enterprise geodatabase or on ArcGIS Online itself AND:  1.  has editor tracking enabled;  2.  has Global IDs;  3.  has Archiving enabled (if you're not already using versioning).  At least ONE of the feature layers in the map must be editable (but you've already covered that).

Comment: @Mapperz to clarify, not a file geodatabase, an enterprise geodatabase

Comment: @SonofaBeach Let me look over the versioning option I think that may be it, also editor tracking?

Comment: With the export basemap did you proxy the service adding it as an item under my content in your portal?  Check this section  Use an Esri basemap on ArcGIS Enterprisehttps://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector/ipad/help/offline-prep.htm

Comment: Don’t turn on versioning just for this.  It creates a whole new world of complications.   Enabling archiving is much better if you don’t need versioning.

Comment: @RussRoberts Well I did add it in my portal... But let me read what you have here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I realized what I was doing wrong and forgot to post.

First the map: I followed this set of instructions [here](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector-classic/android/create-maps/offline-map-prep.htm) and added the map in my organization's content.

Then the layer: I was confused with the configurations involved when publishing the layer but I figured out where I had to "enable sync" and "enable archiving" and GlobalIDs on my layer and published the layer (before I published the layer along with a map in ArcGIS Pro and that was also why it wasn't working)

Then I put together my offline map and syncable layer in my portal and with that I was able to use this in Collector.